# Finding the total are for sf polygons intersecting a grid cell

Tags: r, r-sf

I have two polygons and an equally spaced grid across them. My goal is for each cell to calculate the total area of polygons within each cell.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Create two polygons of equal size area
pol_A = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(1,1), c(0,1), c(0,0))))
polys = st_sfc(pol_A, pol_A + c(-0.97, .05)) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(poly_ID = c("A","B"))

# Create a grid as an sfc and add ID for each cell
gr <- st_make_grid(polys, cellsize = .1, square = T) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(cell_ID = row_number())
```

This gives the following plot:

```
# Plot the grid and polys
plot(gr)
plot(polys,add=T, col = "red")
```

[image]

I want to find the total area of all polygons for each grid cell. It may not be obvious from the picture above, but there are three cells that are intersected by each polygon. So when I calculate the intersection like this:

```
# Generate the intersection
i <- st_intersection(gr, polys) %>%
  mutate(x = st_union(x),
         area_in_cell = st_area(x))
```

I get:

```
Simple feature collection with 142 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -0.97 ymin: 0 xmax: 1 ymax: 1.05
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
First 10 features:
   cell_ID poly_ID                              x area_in_cell
1       10       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
2       11       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
3       30       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
4       31       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
5       32       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
6       50       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
7       51       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
8       52       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
9       53       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
10      70       A MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 0.03 1...            1
```

But when I look at to see if there is only one row per cell in `i` using:

```
overlap_count <- i %>% group_by(cell_ID) %>% summarise(count = n()) %>% arrange(desc(count))
```

I still have three cells with two entries each:

```
Simple feature collection with 139 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -0.97 ymin: 0 xmax: 1 ymax: 1.05
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
# A tibble: 139 x 3
   cell_ID count                                                                                       x
     <int> <int>                                                                          <MULTIPOLYGON>
 1     190     2 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 2     210     2 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 3     211     2 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 4       1     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 5      10     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 6      11     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 7      21     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 8      22     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
 9      30     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
10      31     1 (((0 1, 0.03 1, 0.13 1, 0.23 1, 0.33 1, 0.43 1, 0.53 1, 0.63 1, 0.73 1, 0.83 1, 0.93...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code to draw the polygons and the grid! Very useful question :)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that I was nearly there:

```
st_intersection(gr,polys) %>% 
  group_by(cell_ID) %>% 
  summarise(geom = st_union(x)) %>%
  mutate(geom = st_sfc(geom),
         area = st_area(geom))
```

Does the trick!